# Can SRS technique help math learners?

Tags: learning

I have used [SRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition_system) for learning stuff in other subjects like History and Language in the past (Using [Anki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki)). It seems like a good deal since I get punched with something I was about to forget at the point where I could remember it.

Will SRS help in learning math **on my own**?

The reason I ask (as opposed to trying directly) are:

- The heart of SRS is composing questions. In history, I'd need it for dates and venues. Like *The Normandy landings took place on?*. How should one compose questions for using SRS in mathematics?
  I don't think asking problems is a good idea since it can mislead the learner. For instance, asking the learner Derivative of $x^n$ is? might prompt him to answer that the derivative of $\pi^4$ is $4\pi^3$.
- Theorems are really important but how do you frame them into multiple choice questions?

(I do realize that Math is about understanding rather than memorizing but I quote John Neumann : 
*"Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them."*)

Comment: I think the answer partly depends on what level of maths you are learning, so it might be a good idea to indicate that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do as many problems as you can. Thats the way to learn math.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use it for theorems and things like that, usually you can just prove them yourself if you forget. I do however use SRS to keep myself sharp on problem solving techniques I've learned. I tend to get rusty at solving certain kinds of problems after a while if I haven't done very many. Usually, when I learn an approach to a certain kind of problem, I toss a few into Anki and that keeps me sharp.